# Problem in copy constructor of a abstract class

Tags: c++

How can I insert value in a copy constructor of an abstract class from a derived class

This program is running fine if I delete the virtual function and make an object of the Base class or if I change the copy constructor but I only have access to the Derived class.

```
class Book{
    protected:
        string title;
        string author;
    public:
        Book(string t,string a){
            title=t;
            author=a;
        }
        virtual void display()=0;
};
```

```
class MyBook: private Book
{
public:
    int price;

    MyBook(string t,string a,int p)
    {
        Book(t,a);
        price = p;
    }

    void display()
    {
         ....
    }
};
```

```
int main() {

    string title,author;
    int price;
    getline(cin,title);
    getline(cin,author);
    cin>>price;
    MyBook novel(title,author,price);
    novel.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The syntax for the derived class constructor does not look correct, you should be using initializer lists like so `MyBook(string t,string a,int p) : Book(t,a)`

Comment: There are no copy constructors in the code you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
class MyBook: private Book
{
public:
    int price;

    MyBook(string t, string a, int p) : Book(std::move(t), std::move(a)) {
        price = p;
    }

    void display() override {

    }
};
```

I don't think you're looking for copy constructors by the way. I think you're looking for an explicit constructor. Copy constructor for Book would be `Book(const Book& another)`.

I also have a couple of suggestions if you're using C++ 11 or higher.

1. Use `std::move` to avoid unnecessary copying of string t.
2. Use `override` keyword because it helps you generate compiler errors when you don't exactly match the method signature from the base class. It helps you avoid mistakes of that nature.